# Data from 2 forms on 2 different pages into the same row of an SQL table

Tags: php, html, sql, forms

Im trying to put data from two different forms on two different webpages into the same row of an SQL table. The following is what ive tried to do.

On the first page, ive done a `<?php session_start(); ?>` and defined a variable called `email`. The first form is filled out (one of the entries is the email address) and this data is all inserted into an SQL table using

```
    INSERT INTO `first_page_data` (title, first_name, surname, phone_number, 
email_address, house, street, town, city, postcode) VALUES 
(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
```

The data is added correctly, and the form redirects to a second web page with another form, which needs to be added to the same row of data in the table.

The way Ive thought of doing this is using the session variable which was set as the email address in the first page. I set the value of a hidden field to hold the session variable:

```
  <input type="hidden" name="hiddenField" id="hiddenField" 
value="<?php echo $_SESSION['email']; ?>">
```

And then on form submission the email address here can be matched against the email address already in the database from the previous page, and the new data updated accordingly using:

```
    UPDATE first_page_data SET tod_house=%s, tod_bung=%s, tod_flat=%s,
 tod_barnc=%s, tod_farm=%s, tod_small=%s, tod_build=%s
WHERE email_address=%s",
```

However this doesnt work! I know that the session variable is being passed from the one page to another by using a temporary `echo` to check. My feeling is that it is a problem with setting the value in the hidden field, but im not sure. Any ideas would be welcomed (including different ways of doing what im trying to achieve if this isnt a good way of adding to the database!)

Comment: I think this is not a good way.
BUT; instead of using a hidden value, you can use session in second query like "where email_address=$_SESSION['email']"

Comment: @UğurÖzpınar Ive tried replacing exactly "email_address=%s" with "email_address=$_SESSION['email']" but it throws a syntax error up in dreamweaver. Any ideas? Also if you think this is not a good way, what other way would you suggest?

Comment: I can't suggest you the other way according to your answer:) Where is your %s comes from? You should do the change there

Comment: @UğurÖzpınar why cant you suggest the other way?

Comment: ok. You would put together 2 pages to one page. Like Step 1-Step 2 tabs. All form will be in one page you will not have to use session